# How to share session to every application in intranet ? Asp .Net Core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, ldap

Hi i managed to validate authentication using LDAP and the domain of intranet. I want to build a Web Api that will separate clients from user data.

Users authenticate on web api using ldap, after that they can enter on multiple applications.

The problem here is, I create cookie authentication to store claims on web api. How can i share these cookies with other applications so Web Api can keep track of session of users while using other apps?

Comment: One usually doesn't use Cookies on WebApi endpoints due to security reasons (XSRF - Cross-Site Request Forgery) and scalability. You should use Tokens (JWT or Opaque/Reference Tokens) which are passed with each request via header

Comment: JWT shares authentication (its a json file which contains authentication information and is cryptographically signed to prevent tempering), not session. WebAPI is basically a restful api, which means **stateless** and sessions are state which should be avoided on WebAPI projects

Comment: i see i understand, i will try this approach, thanks